# Product of polynomials that split

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is to prove that polynomials $a, b$ split if and only if their product $ab$ splits.

One direction is easier -- if a and b split, then $a = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$ and $b = (x - s_1)(x - s_2)...(x - s_m)$, so their product $ab = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)(x - s_1)(x - s_2)...(x - s_m)$ clearly splits.

I'm stuck on the other direction, however. If $ab$ splits, then $ab$ can be written as above. How does this show that both $a$ and $b$ themselves split?

Comment: What are $x_1, x_2, ...$? (Funny notation to call polynomials by $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: Whoops, I completely messed up the notation. Editing now for clarity. Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

ab is the product of linear factors, so a and b each must be the product of some of these factors, so they split.  Am I missing something?

Comment: A small subtlety is that this rests on the ring of polynomials (over a field) being a UFD, so that for each linear factor, since it's irreducible and divides $ab$ it must divide one of them.